# restore Oracle database from a DAT file

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

is it possible to restore an oracle database from a DAT file?, and how can I do it? or if there is another way to convert the DAT file. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is a "DAT file"?  How was it generated?  I suppose it is possible that someone used the Oracle export utility (classic or DataPump) to generate a logical backup and used a .dat extension for the file.  It's possible that this is a data file from an Oracle database again with a somewhat non-standard .dat extension.  Or it might be something else.

Comment: one of my clients sent me the .dat file as a backup file, am not expert in Oracle so is it possible to restore the tables from the dat file? Thank you,

Comment: Did your client tell you exactly what the file was?  If not, you'd need to ask your client what they sent you.